# Checking if a Rest Call succeeds in PowerShell

Tags: rest, powershell, error-handling

I'm currently writing a PowerShell script that will remove all users from a tool via Rest API.  The current script works as intended but is lacking in error handling. The only thing I want to check for is if the Rest Call is successfully completed.  After googling, I couldn't really find much or maybe I'm searching the wrong terms. Any thoughts or direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Look at wrapping the command in a `try { } catch { }` block. Microsoft provide documentation to explain this.

Comment: thanks a bunch! I'll definitely look into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of code I've used successfully (assuming you've defined Uri, Headers, and Body if required - also note the Method here is set to Post):

```
    try
    {
        Write-Verbose "Calling $Uri"
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Headers $Headers -Body $Json -ContentType 'application/json' -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch
    {
        throw $_
    }
```